# Use ":active" and "onclick" simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

The problem is this: I have an image on a website. During the duration of a click, the image should be replaced to look like a "clicked-state"... Simultaneously a javascript function should be called...

individualy ":active" and "onclick" are working without a problem, but not combined...

Is there a simple solution?

If "//visibility: hidden;" the onclick() works...

```js
function play0() {
  alert("TEST");
}
```

```css
#play0 {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

#play0:active {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#play1 {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.animation_items {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img class="animation_items" id="play0" onclick="play0()" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg/1200px-SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg.png">
<img class="animation_items" id="play1" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ekthcIHDt3I/maxresdefault.jpg">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I cannot reproduce the problem you are describing. Please include the relevant code that is causing you this problem.

Comment: Please provide some code what you did till now

Comment: [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has some good advice, in particular  the recommendation to include a [mcve].

Comment: @WaisKamal I think he want to show some animation when mouse click occurs and remove it on mouse key is released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this

```js
function clicked(e) {
  alert(e.target.id)
}
document.getElementById("play0").addEventListener("mousedown",clicked)
```

```css
#play0 {
  left: 85px;
  top: 160px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

#play0:active {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#play1 {
  left: 85px;
  top: 160px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.animation_items {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img class="animation_items" id="play0" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg/1200px-SMPTE_Color_Bars.svg.png">
<img class="animation_items" id="play1" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ekthcIHDt3I/maxresdefault.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I have tested it with an alert (instead of the console-command), but it does not pop up..

Comment: Works for me... Reload the answer

Comment: With the snippet tool, it works fine, but when I copy the code into local files, I can't get it to work... Is there something special I have to pay attention to?

Comment: Nothing that I know of. The code has to be AFTER the elements have rendered. Any console error? I am testing in Chrome on Win 10

Comment: That was the problem... I used an external .js-File with the link in <head>... THANK YOU!